# Shell scripting removing negative integer

Tags: shell, variables, scripting

How can we remove negative sign from a integer in shell?

Say `diff=-234`; how can we make `diff=234`?

I tried with

```
if [ $diff -lt 0 ]
then
    diff=$(expr $diff \* -1)
fi
```

but this is not working.

Comment: I've just tested your code since it looks correct to me and it worked like expected. So your problem must be elsewhere in your script.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat the value as a string or as a number, as you wish.  If you treat it as a string, you don't have to do numeric operations:

```
diff=-234
if [ "$diff" -lt 0 ]
then diff=${diff#-}
fi
echo "$diff"
```

You could use `expr` for this too, but that invokes an external process instead of doing it in the shell:

```
diff=-234
if [ "$diff" -lt 0 ]
then diff=$(expr "$diff" : '^-\(.*\)')
fi
echo "$diff"
```

Then you can treat it numerically, in many different ways, including:

```
diff=-234
if [ "$diff" -lt 0 ]
then ((diff *= -1))
fi
echo "$diff"
```

You can also modify the conditional:

```
diff=-234
[ "$diff" -lt 0 ] && ((diff *= -1))
echo "$diff"

diff=-234
[[ "$diff" < 0 ]] && ((diff *= -1))
echo "$diff"

diff=-234
(("$diff" < 0)) && ((diff *= -1))
echo "$diff"

diff=-234
((diff < 0)) && ((diff *= -1))
echo "$diff"

diff=-234
[[ "$diff" < 0 ]] && diff=${diff#-}
echo "$diff"
```

Etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Using shell arithmetic syntax to determine whether the number is negative and, if so, multiply by `-1` to get the positive value.

```
if ((diff < 0)); then let diff*=-1; fi
```

Example:

```
$ diff=-42
$ if ((diff < 0)); then let diff*=-1; fi
$ echo $diff 
42
```